# Sending data into server using httpdelete

Tags: android, web-services, http-delete

I am new in android.Currently i am doing web service connection part in android.Here i am using httpdelete method.But i can't be able to send values into server.Here i attach my code.please give me a solution.The passing JSON object is given below.

```
JSONObject obj = {"encrypted_device_id":"c02c705e98588f724ca046ac59cafece65501e36","card_name":"disc"}
```

**CODE**

```
public String getWebDataDelete(String page,JSONObject obj) 
        {

            String result=null;
            HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
            try 
            {
                  HttpDelete httppost = new HttpDelete(Connector.URL+page);         
                 httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                 httppost.setHeader("api_key", "123456");
                 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString()); 
                 se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                 httppost.setEntity(se); 
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());   

            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {

            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {

            }
            return result;

 }
```

Comment: Are you getting error ? if so pls post it

Comment: Hi i got add cast to httppost in the line  httppost.setEntity(se); .I did that one but at the time some html is return from server

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this one, working for me


  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Url);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(JSONobject.toString(), "UTF-8");
        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        request.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resultentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
        InputStream inputstream = resultentity.getContent();
        result = convertStreamToString(inputstream);


  private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputstream) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputstream));
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return total.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi i need httpdelete method not post